# change sqlite file size after "DELETE FROM table"

Tags: sqlite

I am working with sqlite3 file.

First, I entered relatively big database, file size was about 100 mb.

Than I made

```
$db->exec("DELETE FROM table");
```

and entered just a small part of that database. But file size remained 100 mb.

What should you do to change sqlite file size when deleting it's content?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The command you are looking for is [vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).  There is also a [pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) to turn auto-vacuuming on.

From the documentation:

> When an object (table, index, trigger,
>   or view) is dropped from the database,
>   it leaves behind empty space. This
>   empty space will be reused the next
>   time new information is added to the
>   database. But in the meantime, the
>   database file might be larger than
>   strictly necessary. Also, frequent
>   inserts, updates, and deletes can
>   cause the information in the database
>   to become fragmented - scrattered out
>   all across the database file rather
>   than clustered together in one place.
>
> The VACUUM command cleans the main
>   database by copying its contents to a
>   temporary database file and reloading
>   the original database file from the
>   copy. This eliminates free pages,
>   aligns table data to be contiguous,
>   and otherwise cleans up the database
>   file structure.

Comment: is there a way to restore the not-yet-overriden deleted table rows?

Comment: `VACUUM`ing a database required **twice the size** of the original database file in internal/external memory. Read [SQLite Query Language: VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_vacuum.html) to know more.

Comment: @phil294 your best bet is to load the .db file into a text editor and look for what you want. There's a whole book on the forensic analysis of sqlite databases if you really want to delve into the weeds here.

Answer (score 68):

You can do this

```
$db->exec("DELETE FROM table");
$db->exec("vacuum");
```

and the file size will be changed.

Answer (score -2):

Cleaning Databases
SQLite has two commands designed for cleaning—reindex and vacuum.

reindex is used to rebuild indexes. It has two forms:

```
reindex collation_name;
reindex table_name|index_name;
```

vacuum has the form:

```
VACUUM;
```