# SQLite inserts slow when file is full of free pages

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have an SQLite database on which I am running a particular set of queries. If the database file is new, then these queries run in about half a millisecond.

Now if I fill up a table, and delete everything the file will not shrink, but rather the pages in the sqlite file will be marked as free. However next time I run those same queries, they now take between 9 and 11 milliseconds. That is a slowdown of 20x which worries me. Can anyone shed some light as to why this is happening and what can I do to fix this? (if at all possible)

I am accessing the SQLite database using System.Data.Sqlite on c#

I am also using transactions for this. I know inserts are slow without them, but this problem is definitely not caused by that since I know for sure that I am opening a transaction myself (without a transaction they take upwards of 20 milliseconds)

Comment: maybe this is ane explanation: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: But as I have said in the question, I am already opening a transaction so the problem is not coming from that. If the database file is empty I easily get over 20k queries per second. If the database is not empty then that drops down to about a 100 per second, which is not really that much faster than not using a transaction in the first place. Regarding the synchronous option, I cannot turn that off as I cannot risk database corruption. So there is no way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have the reputation yet to just leave this in the comments, but the answer at:

[This stack overflow quetion - change sqlite file size after “DELETE FROM table”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143800/change-sqlite-file-size-after-delete-from-table)

should go some way to helping out. The command you are looking for is

```
vacuum
```

Comment: Yeah I know about that. I don't know exactly the size of the database. But in some use cases it can reach sizes of up to around 5gb. Vacuum is very expensive then. But I guess it's a necessary evil

Comment: Using the Auto-Vacuum mode may mitigate the expense of the "normal" vacuum - it has a few cons though that might be worth looking into. It does the vacuuming of empty pages at the end of a transaction BUT it does tend to increase fragmentation as it moves files around and doesn't do the de-fragmentation that the 'normal' vacuum performs.