# SQLite Filesize is still not change after drop table

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

1. I have a SQLite Database 4MB.
2. I used command drop table `name`; and I dropped it. I checked in SQlite Manager that no more table `name`.
3. However, I checked the filesize, it is still 4MB, the same.
4. I use NotePade, open the Database I see the old contents which I have inserted are still there.

Did I do anything wrong on drop table command? or SQLite keeps old data and filesize will the same?

Thanks your help.

Comment: It keeps them in the file, but will later overwrite as needed. If I remember correctly, you can do a `vacuum` to clean up old data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143808/2198378

Although file size was same, data will be overridden.

To avoid it, refer [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) and [auto_vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).