# Getting "hidden" history from chromes sqlite file

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, browser-history

Accidentally I cleared chrome history/downloads. Now the history has c.a 30 links and 1 downloaded file. However the `History` SQLite file is ~28MB. If I open it as a plain text, I can see the old urls there. however if I open it in some SQLite browser, I see only the new ones. Anyone has knowledge what could be the case?

Comment: SQLite database files don't shrink; instead, the freed sections of the database are added to a free list. If you want to actually free them and shrink the file, run the `VACUUM` command.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143800/change-sqlite-file-size-after-delete-from-table

Comment: After long fight I was able to extract this data and I inserted it back into SQLite file. Now I can see it in SQLite viewer but chrome doesn't show it in history