# Deleting records in a sqlite db in iOS won't decrease the database size

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, memory, size

I'm currently trying to reduce the size of my database by deleting records from my sqlite database in my iOS application but the size will stay the same (size of all the files associated with the database, i.e. the .sqlite file, the .sqlite-shm file and the .sqlite-wal file). I have read that this is the expected behaviour (Ref: [change sqlite file size after "DELETE FROM table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143800/change-sqlite-file-size-after-delete-from-table)). This link suggests to use the sqlite "vacuum" tool and this should clean up the unused memory fragment. However, by doing this, this allocates a lot of memory in the rollback on disk memory (more specifically, the .sqlite-wal file). So this doesn't help since the total size of the files associated with the database didn't decrease.

I was wondering if anybody has any idea what to do in that case? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

JB

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the use of Write ahead logging (sqlite-wal) in initialisation of your persistent store coordinator (typically in appdelegate) (Check stack overflow or google). This will mean that any changes made to the SQL db are reflected on disk on your device immediately as you appear to be expecting.

It might look something like this:

```
 if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:storeURL
                                                     options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}}
                                                       error:&error])
```

Comment: I'm not using a persistent store coordinator. The app is using the FMDB library (which is essentially just a wrapper on top of the native sqlite3 libraries) and the library is using the Write ahead logging support and there's no way to turn it off. Thoughts?

Comment: There should be an option to turn off the feature in config, initialisation or elsewhere...

Comment: FMDB doesn't expose this. It doesn't allow the client to turn off journaling

Comment: Does sqlite allows turning off journalling ?