# Sqlite File Size not decreasing after deleting some rows from database in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am programatically trying to check the size of `SQLite` database stored on the iphone after deleting some rows. The records get deleted, but the file size remains the same. Is there any way I can get the correct size of file after deleting records from sqlite in iOS? Please see the code below:

```
NSString* databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithString: [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: self.databaseFilename]];
unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                    attributesOfItemAtPath:databasePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

Thanks!

I cant use the vaccum approach because it deletes all the records . I am deleting 50% of data only, and not all. So this is not duplicate of this question
[change sqlite file size after "DELETE FROM table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143800/change-sqlite-file-size-after-delete-from-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change sqlite file size after "DELETE FROM table"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143800/change-sqlite-file-size-after-delete-from-table)

Comment: It is normal for the file size to not decrease. The database will reclaim the space as needed. If you want to force it to rewrite a smaller file, run vacuum.

Comment: Thilo, I am deleting only some records and not all the records. Vaccum helps in case of deleting all the records.

Comment: Vacuum does not delete any data. It just compacts the space used to store it (potentially resulting in a smaller file).

Answer (score 11):

The size of a SQLite database file does not necessarily shrink when records are deleted. If auto_vacuum is not enabled, it will *never* shrink unless you perform a vacuum operation on it.

See https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html and https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum .