# Delete records in one table not present in another: HOW?

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

In a "base" table of SQLite, there is a reference column:

```
refX
```

Another "content" table contains this same column, but many of its records are not listed in the base table.

**How do I delete the records in the "content" table that are NOT in the "base" table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Content WHERE refX NOT IN (SELECT refX FROM Base);
```

Comment: Having deleted tens of thousands of records, the database is still the same size on the disk. Is this normal?

Comment: See [change sqlite file size after “DELETE FROM table”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143800/11654).

Comment: "Attached databases can be vacuumed by appending the appropriate schema-name to the VACUUM statement."

Comment: Sorry, I'm so new to this I have NO IDEA what a schema-name  actually is, what it's talking about... nothing. No clues.